# Is there a industry standard numbers available for sonar results?

Tags: sonarqube, code-metrics

Sonar produces a good setup of numbers and I would like to know if there are industry standard  or threshold numbers available for these indexes it creates? I can assume some of the numbers like Unit test coverage we have to look to reach 100% so anything from 80% up is good. Duplication have to 0%. Violation, we need to bring it to 0. I guess for RCI, we need to get to 100% as well. I am not sure about the complexity. What is the average number we have to at?

#/method

#/class

#/file

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no industry standard for those metrics.

However, it is commonly admitted that the complexity per method should not exceed 10 - which is the default threshold for the "Avoid too complex method" rule in Sonar.